# R : customize the pairs function to plot two different datasets

Tags: r, plot

Here is my problem:

I have two methods that respectively output  the variables X1,X2 and X3 and Y1,Y2 and Y3. I would like to visualise graphically the difference of correlation between (X1,X2 and X3) and (Y1,Y2 and Y3). For that I would like to create a "pairs plot" in which the upper part represents a pair plot between the (X_i) and the lower part a pair plot between the (Y_i).

I tried to use the function documentation to deal with this problem but do not managed to know how to do this. I will appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`? It tells R to make place for two plots in one graphical device one above the other (2x1 matrix). Then simply plot both pairs graphs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Hmm, odd. Perhaps `pairs()` overwrites any layout instructions.